# How to access tomcat running in docker container from browser?

Tags: tomcat, docker, containers, virtualbox

I am running tomcat in my docker container from the Official Repo.

```
docker pull tomcat
```

And as per guidelines stated in the [homepage](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) I've run the instance and the Tomcat server is started

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

And Tomcat server is available on the port 8888. I am able to get the response in the *boot2docker* when I execute the following command

```
curl localhost:8888
```

But I would like to access the page from my web browser installed in my PC (which is out of the Virtual Box, the one that is installed in my Windows). Can I? If so how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may be missing a port forwarding rule in the VirtualBox settings.

```
boot2docker vm > settings > Network > NAT adapter > Port forwarding
```

Note the last entry:

[image]

This way you have configured the whole chain: `hostPort:virtualBoxPort` then `virtualBoxPort:containerPort`, as shown in the following diagram:
[image]

Comment: That is great! Thank you :) So, in a similar way to get on working with new ports, we need to add them to the port forwarding rules. Am I right? By the way, what are Host Port and Guest Port?

Comment: You can update the start.sh Shell script (provided with the Boot2Docker install) so that the desired port forwarding rules are set up once and for all. See for example https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4007#issuecomment-34573044. Otherwise you can add them manually as described above.

Comment: `Host port` is the port on your machine (your PC). The `guest port` is the port of the VM (VirtualBox).

Comment: But I put the same port number for both `Guest` and `Host` ports, but still it worked for me! In my example, `8080` is guest port which is to be mapped with `8888` on the host. But, I copied the same as in your screenshot. How could it be possible?

Comment: I just added a diagram for clarification. Hope it's self explanatory enough :-)

Comment: Just FYI for people not sure how to add it. Start -> virtualbox -> click your box -> Settings -> Network -> Port Forwarding, You can then add the setting above.

Answer (score 8):

Seems there's a better answer available since Docker-Tools was introduced a few months ago. If you're not using Docker Tools, take a look at https://docs.docker.com/machine

If you are using Docker Tools,

1. find the docker machine name with `$ docker-machine ls`
2. find the docker IP address with `$ docker-machine ip <machine-name>`
3. use the ip address to connect, e.g. `$ curl 192.168.99.100`

Answer (score 3):

run `boot2docker ip` to get the IP of your docker bridge. Then you can run `curl BRIDGE_IP:8888`
The IP will be something like 192.168.59.103. With boot2docker the VMs networking stack is not your local host but running on a virtual interface.

Comment: `Failed to get VM Host only IP Address. Was the VM initialized using boot2docker?` I am getting this error.

Comment: I've modified the start.sh file and somehow managed to get the IP address, but still I ain't able to open http://192.168.59.105:8888 in the browser but I am able to get response using `curl` in boot2docker

Comment: I saw the same when running from the windows shell, and found out the
`boot2docker ip`
command must be run from the Git Bash shell.

Answer (score 1):

option `-p` has argument `hostPort:containerPort` so in your case port 8080 (inside your docker image) is mapped to port 8888 on the host (your windows box). This means you should be able to find the tomcat on your Windows box by appending `:8888` to your URL, just like you did with curl.

Comment: No, I am getting 'Unable to connect' error when I am trying to open `http://localhost:8888` in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Using `docker-machine ls` to get the IP of the Virtual Box instance running the container. Then use that with the associated port you exposed, in my case 8080, so it was `http://192.168.99.100:8080`.