# using docker/containers + not able to visit server in browser

Tags: tomcat, curl, docker, containers

I am running tomcat in my docker container.

> My question is why can I go here in cygwin 192.168.59.103:8888 (using curl or lynx) and not in my firefox browser?

I am on a windows7 machine with cygwin and boot2docker

my ip on my windows machine (doing an ipconfig /all in cygwin)

```
10.201.202.25(Preferred)
```

my boot 2 docker ip (rung in cygwin)

```
$ boot2docker ip
192.168.59.103
```

running this command in docker to get the container running

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0
```

this is the server up and running

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
c1b19bf099f0        tomcat:8            "catalina.sh run"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8888->8080/tcp   high_feynman
```

the IP address of the container I am running is `172.17.0.2`

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker inspect high_feynman | grep IP
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "fe80::42:acff:fe11:2",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
docker@boot2docker:~$
```

works

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl localhost:8080 | head
```

does not work

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl localhost:8888 | head
```

works

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl 172.17.0.2:8080 | head
```

does not work

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ curl 172.17.0.2:8888 | head
```

From cygwin: does not work

```
$ curl 192.168.59.103:8080 | head
```

From cygwin: works

```
$ curl 192.168.59.103:8888 | head
```

**NOTE** This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471688/how-to-access-tomcat-running-in-docker-container-from-browser) but I have set up prtforwarding on my vm as requested but it still does not work. Is there anything else that I can do?

Answer (score 0):

had to untick `Automatically detect settings` for chrome to work

had to tick `use system proxy settings` in Firefox

I am not sure what exactly this means if anyone would like to comment? 
And I do not think I have to do the port forwarding that is mention in the other question