# run nginx in docker with another application

Tags: linux, nginx, docker

I have my application that needs to serve on port `:5000`

Here's my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN service nginx restart

RUN go get github.com/a/mycmd

EXPOSE 5000
```

And I run

```
sudo docker run --publish 5000:5000 --rm app /go/bin/mycmd
```

And here's my nginx config file:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limit:10m rate=2r/s;

server {
    listen 80;

    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
    server_name 123.13.13.13 example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 3000s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        limit_req zone=limit burst=5 nodelay;
    }
}
```

Then I expect this to redirect traffic from the webserver (port `80`) to my app port `5000`, but seems like `nginx` doesn't do the reverse proxy correctly. Traffic do not get directed to my app.

How do I set up nginx and my app in the same container so that I can use it as a reverse proxy?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot read much from its current form. Can you provide the exact Dockerfile and `docker run` command?

Comment: And more important the nginx configuration file

Comment: Just added some more information. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention in the nginx config:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

But you want to redirect to the EXPOSE'd port 5000.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
```

If it is a typo, then make sure you publish 80 to and host port (ot that you are using the container IP address directly.

Don't forget that, if you areusing a VM, you might have to port-forward that published port: see "[Connect to a Service running inside a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019160/6309)"

Comment: Sorry that was my typo. :(

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas OK, I have edited the answer. Are you using docker directly in a Linux host, or through a VM on Windows or Mac?

Comment: I am using Google cloud VM. Redirected port 80 to 5000. now works. Thought I didn't need that. Good to know! Thanks