# OSX 10.11.3 Install gitlab server using docker

Tags: macos, docker, gitlab

My English not good, sorry!
I install gitlab server using docker.

First I install Docker Toolbox,and then I follow the steps below：

Step 1. Launch a postgresql container

```
docker run --name gitlab-postgresql -d \
--env 'DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production' \
--env 'DB_USER=gitlab' --env 'DB_PASS=password' \
--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql \
sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-12
```

Step 2. Launch a redis container

```
docker run --name gitlab-redis -d \

--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/redis:/var/lib/redis \
sameersbn/redis:latest
```

Step 3. Launch the gitlab container

```
docker run --name gitlab -d \
--link gitlab-postgresql:postgresql --link gitlab-redis:redisio \
--publish 10022:22 --publish 10080:80 \
--env 'GITLAB_PORT=10080' --env 'GITLAB_SSH_PORT=10022' \
--env 'GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=long-and-random-alpha-numeric-string' \
--volume /srv/docker/gitlab/gitlab:/home/git/data \
sameersbn/gitlab:8.4.2
```

After the end，I can by http://192.168.99.100:10080 access to gitlab server, and can create a project, but I can't through the http://localhost:10080 access to gitlab server, others can not upload and download， should not do port forwarding, I should how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should not do port forwarding

Well actually yuo should do a port-forward 10080 to your actual host (Windows or Mac) through the VM which hosts the boot2docker-based Linux.
See "[Connect to a Service running inside a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019160/6309)"

```
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "tcp-port10080,tcp,,10080,,10080"
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "udp-port10080,udp,,10080,,10080"
```

(Replace `default` with the name of your docker-machine: see `docker-machine ls`)

Comment: bash-3.2$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   URL          STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER   ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.9.1

Comment: When I execute the command : VBoxManage controlvm "default" --natpf1 "tcp-port10080 ,tcp,,10080,,10080"      show the error : Syntax error: Invalid parameter '--natpf1'