# Why https is forced?

Tags: docker

When I start the container that has nginx running, I try to view it in the browser, the https is enforced, and although nginx is running in the container with the right volume mapping, I only see:

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

I tried different ports, but I got the same result.
I am using Docker version 1.10.1, OSX Capitan

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure:

- your NGiNX image does [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) port 80
- your [`docker run` command does map port 80](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) (to for example the host port 80 if it is free: `docker run -p 80:80`)
- your VM does [port-forward port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35146305/6309) (if you are not using docker directly on Linux, but through a boot2docker VM, which is the case here)
- your nginx.conf does serve something when trying to access the main page (`http://<your-nginx>/`)

Comment: I' ve checked the above list, if I try http 192.168.99.100:800/ the browser will redirect to https 192.168.99.100 and I get 404 error, if I use https 192.168.99.100:800/ I get ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR , why the redirect, why can't I view it in http ?