# Not able to access tomcat application on Docker VM with host(windows) IP while using docker toolbox

Tags: windows, tomcat, docker

I am running docker on my windows system using docker toolbox. I ran tomcat container using command `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0`. As per documentation I should be able to access tomcat using http://localhost:8888, but this is not working.

Rather, I can access the tomcat app using docker-machine ip which is http://192.168.99.100:8888.

But this is not what I need. I need to access the tomcat container app from outside my system itself, through the network. So, how do I map tomcat application  to my windows host system ?

While googling around, I could see an option of port-forwarding for boot2docker vm. But, again I am not using boot2docker. I am using docker toolbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find where to add the port-forwarding rule. Open the oracle VirtualBox Manager. Go to **Settings**-->Network --> Port Forwarding..

Here 1 rule is already available for ssh. 
So I added another rule for this with below configurations:
HostIP:HostPort=> 127.0.0.1:9999
GuestIP:GuestPort=> :8888

So now if I invoke http://localhost:9999 , it is forwarded to => docker-machine:8888  and from there it is forwarded to => tomcatVM:8080.

Comment: You don't need to use the GUI: VBoxManage *is* available. Just add the installation path of VirtualBox to your path.

Comment: And you don't need to use a different port (unless 8888 was already used on your host)

Comment: Spent hours on searching for this answer on Docker docs. The official Docs are rIdiculous in some way and this two different "Docker Toolbox / docker-machine" with VirtualBox Manager and "just Docker" without VirtualBox Manager makes research complicated. Thanks for that posting!
But... `HostIP:HostPort=>127.0.0.1:9999 GuestIP:GuestPort=>:8888` only helped me to open my site on the servers local browser - not reachable by any other computer (by using the servers IP:8888). Had to leave the "source IP" blank `HostIP:HostPort =>:9999 GuestIP:GuestPort=>:8888` (like _VonC_ s commandline-solution)

Answer (score 1):

> I could see an option of port-forwarding for boot2docker vm. But, again I am not using boot2docker. I am using docker toolbox.

Yes, you are using boot2docker.
Toolbox is just a bundle of boot2docker + docker-machine + [kitematic](https://kitematic.com/).

Open your VirtualBox, and you will see a VM which, in the **storage** settings, is based on `boot2docker.iso`.

See do port-forward 8888 to your host: see "[Connect to a Service running inside a docker container from outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35019160/6309)"

```
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "tcp-port8888,tcp,,8888,,8888"
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "udp-port8888,udp,,8888,,8888"
```

(Replace `default` with the name of your docker-machine: see `docker-machine ls`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @VonC. But VBoxManage command is not available in the Docker quickStart terminal or virtualBox VM console. Again, I am on windows7 OS and am using docker toolbox.

Comment: @urOutsourced, if you also separately install VirtualBox, you can run the VBoxManage command on the VirtualBox VM that Docker Toolbox launches.