# Docker - Cannot forward ports for an interactive shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, shell, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am getting so many difficulties with forwarding ports in docker containers. First I tried to forward ports for an existing container. Then I realize that this is not possible. So I tried with docker run command (create a new container from the docker image).

```
 docker run -p 8080:8080 -td <image_id>
```

I checked with docker ps command and its showing these ports under the 'Ports' heading. But I used -d (Run container in background) option here. So it worked I guess.

But I really needed a interactive shell and here I want to forward some ports.

Basically I am trying to run a Ruby On Rails application (need ports 3000, 3306 etc to be forwarded) in this container and I installed all the software and rails gem etc and started the server in this interactive shell. But I don't know how to forward the ports for an interactive shell.

I tried the following:

```
 docker run -p 3000:3000  -p 3001:3001 -p 3306:3306 -p 5432:5432 -t -i <image_id> /bin/bash
```

Here interactive shell works but ports are not being forwarded.

**EDIT**:
The steps I followed:

```
   $ docker run -p 3000:3000  -p 3001:3001 -p 3306:3306 -p 5432:5432 -t -i 5c62899c063f /bin/bash
   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/# ls
   bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/# cd home/

   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/home# cd rails/
   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/home/rails# ls
   my_project
   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/home/rails# cd my_project/
   root@342cf0dfb5a5:/home/rails/my_project# ls
   Gemfile  Gemfile.lock  README.rdoc  Rakefile  app  bin  config  config.ru  db  lib  log  public  test  tmp  vendor

   root@340cf0dfb5a5:/home/rails/my_project# rails s -b 0.0.0.0

   => Booting WEBrick                                                       
   => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                        
   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                             
   [2016-03-15 05:57:14] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1                                
   [2016-03-15 05:57:14] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]       
   [2016-03-15 05:57:14] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=113 port=3000
```

Still, when I go to localhost:3000, I can't access my application. I wonder whats the issue with port forwarding in docker interactive shell container. As I mentioned above the 'Forwarded ports shows nothing' when listing the containers. So I doubt the above port forwarding command with -p option not works with interactive shell.

[image: listing the container]

**Solution**: 
What I done to solve this issue as per the answer from VonC

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `But I don't know how to forward the ports for an interactive shell`? Does the second command you write not work as you need? If so, why?

Comment: @Auzias I mean -i option here. -it option gives me an terminal to work with the container. But with this option as I mentioned above the ports are not forwarding. I don't know why.I mean After I run 'docker run -p 3000:3000  -p 3001:3001 -p 3306:3306 -p 5432:5432 -t -i <image_id> /bin/bash', the ports not forwarding. Forwarded ports shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Forwarded ports shows nothing

It might shows nothing within the container in the interactive shell, but those ports are certainly mapped to the Linux *host* port.

In another host Linux shell, do a `docker inspect <yourContainer>`: you will see all the ports as mapped to the host, meaning a curl http://localhost:3000 would work.

Note: on PC, you need to port forward this port at the VirtualBox level.
See "[Not able to access tomcat application on Docker VM with host(windows) IP while using docker toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309)"

```
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "tcp-port3000,tcp,,3000,,3000"
VBoxManage controlvm "default" natpf1 "udp-port3000,udp,,3000,,3000"
```

Comment: Hi @VonC I edited the question with all my steps that taken me to this problem. Please check it. I cannot use docker, because of this issue. So thinking to move to other alternative.

Comment: The docker inspect <container_id>, shows "Ports": null, under "NetworkSettings": {..

Comment: },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3000/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3000"
                    }
                ]
            },

Comment: Try and map 3000 to an higher port like 30300

Comment: @Abhi and of course, you need to make sure your app is not "Exited" and remains up.

Comment: haha, yea. I tried this:
localadmin@dell-PC  ~                                                     
$ docker run -p 30300:3000 -t -i abhilashak/rails-test:version1 /bin/bash 
root@02de071d71a6:/# cd home/rails/my_project/
root@02de071d71a6:/home/rails/my_project# rails s -b 0.0.0.0

"NetworkMode": "default",         
"PortBindings": {                 
    "3000/tcp": [                 
        {                         
            "HostIp": "",         
            "HostPort": "30300"   
        }                         
    ]                             
},

Comment: @Abhi actually, try to map the other ports as well on higher ports `-p 30001:3001 -p 30306:3306 -p 30432:5432`

Comment: and I went to http://localhost:30300 , my local port. But it shows connection refused. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: @Abhi if you are using docker through boot2docker, you also need to port-forward port 30300 on your Windows host: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309

Comment: I am not using boot2docker .And I am using conEmu terminal.

Comment: @Abhi if you are using docker on a PC, you areusing boot2docker and VirtualBox. As mentioned before, port-forward 30300 at the virtualbox level

Comment: I installed docker by following this https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/
there is no installation specified for boot2docker. I think its an old/another type of installation. I installed dockerToolBox and set it up. And need to forward ports in virtual box level?

Comment: @Abhi Exactly: VirtualBox and boot2docker. Again, port-forward at VirtualBox level: read http://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309

Comment: Correct! This solved the issue. Please add this vm port forwarding thing to your answer so that I can accept it. Again thank you for your precious time.