# How to access container's web application from host

Tags: docker

I am running a site inside Docker container which exports following
https://172.17.0.2:8443/admin/  &
http://172.17.0.2:8463/users/

```
$ docker run -it -d --expose=8000-9900 ubuntu-java8-webapp
bf193d011fd8....
```

**Docker PS cmd**

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND      PORTS          NAMES
bf193d011fd8   ubuntu-.... "/bin/bash"  8000-9900/tcp  desperate_mclean
```

**Docker ls cmd**

```
$ docker-machine ls    
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL          DOCKER    ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v1.10.3
```

**Docker machine ip cmd**

```
$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

How do I access the site? Just in case it matters, I am running docker on Mac here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try and access it through the docker machine IP:

```
https://192.168.99.100:8443/admin
http://192.168.99.100:8463/users
```

But ideally, you would:

- map those port to the host:

  ```
  docker run -p 8443:8443 -p 8463:8463 ...
  ```
- [port-forward those port to your actual host through VirtualBox VM Network setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309), and access the site with:

  https://localhost:8443/admin
  http://localhost:8463/users

Comment: Tried with -p 8443:8443 -p 8463:8463 & URL as given above would work. Will try port-forwarding next.