# docker running splash container but localhost does not load (windows 10)

Tags: docker, web-scraping, localhost, scrapy

I am following [this tutorial](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/) to use splash to help with scraping webpages.I installed Docker toolbox and did these two steps:

```
$ docker pull scrapinghub/splash
$ docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 8051:8051 scrapinghub/splash
```

I think it is running correctly, based on the prompted message in Docker window, which looks like this:

[image]

However, when I open the `localhost:8050' in a web browser, it says the localhost is not working.
[image]

What might have gone wrong in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mapped the port to your docker host (the VM), but you have not port-forwarded that same port to your actual "localhost" (your Windows host)

You need to declare that port-forwarding in the [Network settings of your VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771161/6309) (for instance "default"), or with [`VBoxManage controlvm` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309).

Then and only then could you access that port (used by your VM) from your Windows host (`localhost`).

That or you can access that same port using the IP address of your boot2docker VM: see `docker-machine ls`.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the `Network settings of VM`. Instead I used `http://192.168.99.100/8050/` and it works fine. I think when I input `http://localhost`, the computer does not know I am specifically asking for IP address 192.168.99.100. Thank you!

Comment: @user3768495 port-forwarding would have allowed you to use localhost, because that port would have been mapped to the right docker-machine ip.

Answer (score 1):

@user3768495, when you use http://192.168.99.100:8050/ , you are actually using the docker-machine ip and this ip would be available on your machine only and not on the network. To map it to localhost, you do need to port-forward the same port to your localhost. I was having the same issue and I detailed the process in below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35737787/4820675