# error of python module for docker and splashr

Tags: r, docker, web-scraping, splash-screen

I have installed docker and image of splash by

```
docker pull scrapinghub/splash
```

and started the container by

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash
```

which its result can be seen in the picture below
[image]

but, the problem is that in R after running `install_splash()` I receive this error:

```
Error: Python module docker was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\m-joudy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/m-joudy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\m-joudy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
version:        3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:           [NOT FOUND]
docker:         [NOT FOUND]

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\m-joudy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\\python.exe
 C:\Users\m-joudy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\\python.exe
```

Comment: And what is your question? What did you expect?

Comment: well, I cant run splash. how can I fix this error in order to start splash?

Answer (score 0):

From `splashr`'s [README](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/splashr/blob/master/README.md) we learn that the `docker` commands you used and `install_splash()` are *alternatives*, i.e. after

```
docker pull scrapinghub/splash
docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash
```

you should be ready to use

```
library(splashr)
splash_active()
```

and be set to use `splash` via `splashr`. If you still want to make `install_splash()` work, then the error message you quoted tells us, that the python modules `docker` and `numpy` are missing. How you install python packages depends on your installation, but one poular way is to use `pip`, i.e.

```
pip install numpy
pip install docker
```

Potentially within a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Comment: after commands `library(splashr)` and `splash_active()`, I receive `FALSE` .How should I set to use `splash` via `splashr` ?

Comment: @mjoudy Was the docker container running when you tried these commands? This works out of the box on my Linux machine.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `jsonlite::fromJSON("http://localhost:8050/_ping")` when the docker container is running?

Comment: yes, it is running! the last state of docker is like the above picture. And, I am wondering if should it be like that? I mean, in this state there is not any possibility to write a new command.

Comment: it is the output:
`> jsonlite::fromJSON("http://localhost:8050/_ping")`

`Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Failed to connect to localhost port 8050: Connection refused`

Comment: @mjoudy Docker on Windows seems to be different. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891939/docker-running-splash-container-but-localhost-does-not-load-windows-10