# Unable to run docker project in localhost

Tags: docker

I have installed a repo from docker and ran it using the following command,

```
 docker run -d --name searx -p $PORT:8888 wonderfall/searx
```

The container was also sucessfully created but while accessing it in my browser i get the following error,

```
 dail tcp[::1]:8888: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs? I use a windows10 system.

[image]

Comment: try `docker run -d --name searx -p 8888:8888 wonderfall/searx` and access using `localhost:8888`

Comment: What is `docker ps -a` result? Created is not enough, it has to be Up and running.

Comment: @farhad I tried it but same error persists             YOU -- yah all are running !!

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox or Hyper-V? (ie: docker toolbox, or docker for Windows?)

Comment: Nope i have not done any virtualization steps. Just installed docker toolbox and it defaultly installed oracle virtual box. Do i have to perform any virtualization steps ??

Comment: use `ipconfig /all`, find out docker ip, access that ip instead of localhost. docker does not run natively on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just installed docker toolbox

That means you cannot use localhost directly without declaring in Virtual Box a port-forwarding rule.

First, test your service using the IP of your VM (see `docker-machine ip default` output)

```
http://<ip>:8888
```

Then, declare a port-forward rule:

- either directly in your VirtualBox graphical interface: see "[How do I configure docker compose to expose ports correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37771161/6309)"
- or with `VBoxManage controlvm` commands: see "[Not able to access tomcat application on Docker VM with host(windows) IP while using docker toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35646587/6309)"

Comment: Well u kind of gave me the aswer. I must not use localhost. I must place my ipaddress there. Thanks!

Comment: @user3649118 yes, but you could use `localhost:8888`, if you define a port-forwarding rule as I mention.