# Metabase on docker not getting exposed

Tags: docker, windows-7, docker-for-windows, metabase

I'm having some trouble trying to get metabase running on docker.

I've installed Docker for Windows 7 following this [tutotial](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/).

Here is the docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.05.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.1
  Git commit:   f150324
  Built:        Wed May  9 22:20:42 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

Now when I try to get the metabase running on docker, using

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name metabase metabase/metabase
```

and using

```
docker logs -f metabase
```

I get the message after all the setup:

> Metabase Initialization COMPLETE

The problem is when I try to access http://0.0.0.0:3000 I get a ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID. I looked for all the ports that are "LISTENING" using

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```

I don't see the 0.0.0.0:3000 listed there.

Docker ps returns:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
6a283cf6b8d7        metabase/metabase   "/app/run_metabase.sh"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours          0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   metabase
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with metabase image or with docker itself.

Does anyone have an idea on what this could be?

Comment: What command did you run to start the container? What is the output of `docker ps`?

Comment: @sp0gg Just edited with those infos.

Comment: The image looks good - I ran the exact command you did and I was able to see the site on `localhost:3000`. I, however, am running Linux, so I am not sure how to help troubleshoot the Windows element of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address, but [a non-routable meta-address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)
Your application is reachable on your machines IP address / hostname on port 3000.

If you are unsure, what your hostname is, you can run in powershell;

```
hostname
```

And then access it using http://your_hostname:3000

Comment: I get a refused connection when trying this way. I guess this can be some sort of user permission?

Comment: With docker toolbox try `docker-machine ip` to get the proper IP. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642821/not-able-to-access-tomcat-application-on-docker-vm-with-hostwindows-ip-while-u