# Does "ports" on docker-compose.yml have the same effect as EXPOSE on Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Does declaring on a docker-compose.yml:

```
ports:
 - "3306:3306"
```

and on Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 3306
```

have the same effect?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [`ports` directive](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in `docker-compose.yml` and the [`EXPOSE` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) in a Dockerfile serve different purposes and do not have the same effect.

### **Dockerfile**: `EXPOSE 3306`

```
Container
+-----------------+
|                 |
|   Application   |
|      Port       | --> 3306 (EXPOSED, not accessible from host by default)
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

That instruction is a way of documenting which ports the container listens on at runtime. It does not actually publish the port.
It serves as a form of documentation and is used by the `docker run -P` command to allocate a random high-numbered port on the host and map it to the exposed port.

### **docker-compose.yml**: `ports: - "3306:3306"`

```
Host System
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
|                 |      |                 |
|   Host Port     | <--> |   Container     |
|      3306       | <--> |      Port       | --> 3306 (Accessible from host)
|                 |      |                 |
+-----------------+      +-----------------+
```

That directive actually maps the port on the host to the port in the container.
`"3306:3306"` means map port 3306 on the host to port 3306 in the container.

In this setup, the `EXPOSE` directive in the Dockerfile is optional since `docker-compose.yml` is already mapping the ports. The main effect of `EXPOSE` is for documentation and compatibility with certain commands and orchestrators that might use this information.

Comment: Docker updated the documentation and now it is very clear:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run..

Like VonC mentioned, the run -p part can be done with docker-compose.yml (the ports field).

Comment: @RotemJackoby I agree. I was reminded of that specification in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414537/6309.

Comment: But does that means that if I use `ports: "80:80"` in `docker-compose`, I don't need to write `EXPOSE 80` in my Dockerfile, right?

Comment: @Frondor No: see the "as comment" section at the beginnig of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414537/6309

Comment: @VonC is your answer (e.g. to the Frondor's question) outdated? According to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414479/containerized-node-server-inaccessible-with-server-listenport-127-0-0-1/35414537#comment85873631_35414537), `EXPOSE` in Dockerfile is unnecessary. Though `ports:` in docker-compose.yml may be rather important.

Comment: @Johan True, thank you for this feedback. I have rewritten (in 2024) this 2016 answer to make your observation clearer. Let me know if I missed anything.