# Why can't I map the port from my postgres Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created a postgres container from the official posgres image.  I am trying to map the port 5432 so I can access the container from my localhost.

If I expose the port through the `Dockerfile`, the mapping doesn't happen.  Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM postgres

EXPOSE 5432:5432
```

When I build the image and run this, here is what I get when I run `docker ps` it see this in the `PORTS` column `5432/tcp`

When I remove the `EXPOSE` from the `Dockerfile` and build this

```
FROM postgres
```

And then build the image and pass the port on the command line `docker run -p 5432:5432 -d postgres`, the port does get mapped.  When I run `docker ps` I see `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp` in the `PORTS` column.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I expose the ports in the `Dockerfile` in a manner that they will get mapped?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does "ports" on docker-compose.yml have the same effect as EXPOSE on Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548843/does-ports-on-docker-compose-yml-have-the-same-effect-as-expose-on-dockerfile)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish the ports defined inside your Dockerfile with the EXPOSE command, you can use the `-P` flag:

```
docker run -P <container>
```

EXPOSE doesn't actually do anything by itself. As mentioned in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on
>   the specified network ports at runtime.
>
> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.