# Running json-server in docker

Tags: javascript, docker, json-server

I've been running [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) in a docker container for a while successfully with the following config:

Docker File:

```
FROM node:alpine    
EXPOSE 3000
COPY deploy/conf/mockBackend.json /opt/mockBackend.json
RUN yarn global add json-server
CMD ["json-server", "/opt/mockBackend.json"]
```

Run command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name mockbackend mockbackend
```

Recently this stopped working. I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
 in the browser.

By default json-server binds to `127.0.0.1`, which could cause this issue if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414479/docker-ports-are-not-exposed) is correct.

I don't know why it worked before, but binding json server to every interface with `json-server -H 0.0.0.0 mockBackend.json` makes it work again.

My problem now is that starting `json-server` that way in the image manually works fine, but when I change the `CMD` line of the Dockerfile to `CMD ["json-server", "-H 0.0.0.0", "/opt/mockBackend.json"]` I get the folloing error:

Docker log:

```
  \{^_^}/ hi!

  Loading /opt/mockBackend.json
  Done

  Resources
  http:// 0.0.0.0:3000/xxx
  http:// 0.0.0.0:3000/yyy

  Home
  http:// 0.0.0.0:3000

  Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND  0.0.0.0
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:50:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1498:12)
```

It looks like the `json-server` is starting fine, but then exits with the error. Any idea why this only happens when starting the container with the CMD line, but not when running the same `json-server` command manually inside the same image?

Comment: The `-H` and `0.0.0.0` should be split like `CMD ["json-server", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "/opt/mockBackend.json"]`

Not sure if that's the only issue here, but try correcting that first.

Comment: Thanks, that actually fixed the issue! Thoug I still don't unterstand why it worked before when json-server was bound to 127.0.0.1

Comment: The real error was a problem with my reverse proxy. The server is publicly available but hosted on a dynamic IP.  All my dns scripts where working except the one for this mock Backend. Thats why it "randomly" stopped working once the dynamic IP changed.