# Not access json server on docker

Tags: docker, json-server

I have a problem when I try to access a json server on docker, no errors, no response. I tried to access using telnet and return was "Connection closed by foreign host"

My docker-compose is like

```
version: "3"
services:
  json-server:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "3080:3080"
    command: ["yarn", "start:server"]
```

my command yarn start:server is running like:

```
json-server --watch --port 3080 ./db/data.json
```

The container still running, no errors, no response is like not accessible. The response from telnet localhost 3080 is:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly need a `--host 0.0.0.0` option; see also [Running json-server in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784868/running-json-server-in-docker) (this detail is in the question, not an answer).

Comment: exactly this, I tried to force my local ip and doesn't work, but setting 0.0.0.0 works! Thank you