# Expose port using DockerOperator

Tags: docker, airflow, dockeroperator

I am using [DockerOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html) to run a container. But I do not see any related option to publish required port. I need to publish a webserver port when the task is triggered. Any help or guide will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know anything about this field, but shouldn't there be some code here? Ignore me, if no code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't forget [`docker_operator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/docker_operator/index.html) is deprecated, replaced (now) with [`providers.docker.operators.docker`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/_api/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker/index.html#module-airflow.providers.docker.operators.docker).

Second, I don't know of a command to expose a port in a live (running) Docker container.
As described in [this article](https://medium.com/@utter_babbage/exposing-ports-on-live-containers-63538a53a5df) from [Sidhartha Mani](https://twitter.com/utter_babbage)

> Specifically, I needed access to the filled mysql database. .
> I could think of a few ways to do this:
>
> - Stop the container and start a new one with the added port exposure. `docker run -p 3306:3306 -p 8080:8080 -d java/server`.
> - The second option is to start another container that links to this, and knows how to port forward.
> - Setup iptables rules to forward a host port into the container.

So:

> Following existing rules, I created my own rule to forward to the container
>
> ```
> iptables -t nat -D DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp --dport 3306-j DNAT \
>          --to-destination 172.17.0.2:3306
> ```
>
> This just says that whenever a packet is destined to port 3306 on the host, forward it to the container with ip 172.17.0.2, and its port 3306.
>
> Once I did this, I could connect to the container using host port 3306.
> I wanted to make it easier for others to expose ports on live containers.
> So, I created a [small repository and a corresponding docker image](https://github.com/wlan0/redirect) (named `wlan0/redirect`).
>
> The same effect as exposing host port 3306 to container 172.17.0.2:3306 can be achieved using this command.
> This command saves the trouble of learning how to use iptables.
>
> ```
> docker run --privileged -v /proc:/host/proc \
>            -e HOST_PORT=3306 -e DEST_IP=172.17.0.2 -e DEST_PORT=3306 \
>            wlan0/redirect:latest
> ```

In other words, this kind of solution would not be implemented from a command run in the container, through an Airflow Operator.

---

> As per my understanding DockerOperator will create a new container, then why is there no way of exposing ports while create a new container.

First, the `EXPOSE` part is, as I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51340259/6309), just a metadata added to the image. It is not mandatory.
The runtime (`docker run`) `-p` option is about publishing, not exposing: publishing a port and mapping it to a host port (see above) or another container port.
That might be not needed with an Airflow environment, where there is a default network, and even the [possibility to setup a custom network or subnetwork](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-3931).

Which means other (Airflow) containers attached to the same network should be able to access a ports of any container in said network, without needing any `-p` (publication) or `EXPOSE` directive.

Comment: No, it's not about exposing ports to existing container. As per my understanding DockerOperator will create a new container, then why is there no way of exposing ports while create a new container. Thank you for pointing that it is deprecated, but unfortunately I am on 1.10 only.

Comment: @Nabin OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yup, EXPOSE is just an metadata. But  you what I mean, right? I need to publish those port.

Comment: @Nabin I understand. If it is publishing the port for another external service to access to, I don't see a way, except (as described in the first part of my answer) playing with iptables.

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you will need to subclass the `DockerOperator` and override the initializer and `_run_image_with_mounts` method, which uses the API client to create a container with the specified host configuration.

```
class DockerOperatorWithExposedPorts(DockerOperator):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.port_bindings = kwargs.pop("port_bindings", {})
        if self.port_bindings and kwargs.get("network_mode") == "host":
            self.log.warning("`port_bindings` is not supported in `host` network mode.")
            self.port_bindings = {}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _run_image_with_mounts(
        self, target_mounts, add_tmp_variable: bool
    ) -> Optional[Union[List[str], str]]:
        """

        NOTE: This method was copied entirely from the base class `DockerOperator`, for the capability
        of performing port publishing. 
        """
        if add_tmp_variable:
            self.environment['AIRFLOW_TMP_DIR'] = self.tmp_dir
        else:
            self.environment.pop('AIRFLOW_TMP_DIR', None)
        if not self.cli:
            raise Exception("The 'cli' should be initialized before!")
        self.container = self.cli.create_container(
            command=self.format_command(self.command),
            name=self.container_name,
            environment={**self.environment, **self._private_environment},
            ports=list(self.port_bindings.keys()) if self.port_bindings else None,
            host_config=self.cli.create_host_config(
                auto_remove=False,
                mounts=target_mounts,
                network_mode=self.network_mode,
                shm_size=self.shm_size,
                dns=self.dns,
                dns_search=self.dns_search,
                cpu_shares=int(round(self.cpus * 1024)),
                port_bindings=self.port_bindings if self.port_bindings else None,
                mem_limit=self.mem_limit,
                cap_add=self.cap_add,
                extra_hosts=self.extra_hosts,
                privileged=self.privileged,
                device_requests=self.device_requests,
            ),
            image=self.image,
            user=self.user,
            entrypoint=self.format_command(self.entrypoint),
            working_dir=self.working_dir,
            tty=self.tty,
        )
        logstream = self.cli.attach(container=self.container['Id'], stdout=True, stderr=True, stream=True)
        try:
            self.cli.start(self.container['Id'])

            log_lines = []
            for log_chunk in logstream:
                log_chunk = stringify(log_chunk).strip()
                log_lines.append(log_chunk)
                self.log.info("%s", log_chunk)

            result = self.cli.wait(self.container['Id'])
            if result['StatusCode'] != 0:
                joined_log_lines = "\n".join(log_lines)
                raise AirflowException(f'Docker container failed: {repr(result)} lines {joined_log_lines}')

            if self.retrieve_output:
                return self._attempt_to_retrieve_result()
            elif self.do_xcom_push:
                if len(log_lines) == 0:
                    return None
                try:
                    if self.xcom_all:
                        return log_lines
                    else:
                        return log_lines[-1]
                except StopIteration:
                    # handle the case when there is not a single line to iterate on
                    return None
            return None
        finally:
            if self.auto_remove == "success":
                self.cli.remove_container(self.container['Id'])
            elif self.auto_remove == "force":
                self.cli.remove_container(self.container['Id'], force=True)
```

Explanation: The `create_host_config` method of the `APIClient` has an optional `port_bindings` keyword argument, and `create_container` method has an optional `ports` argument. These calls aren't exposed in the `DockerOperator`, so you have to copy the `_run_image_with_mounts` method and override it with a copy and supply those arguments with the `port_bindings` field set in the initializer. You can then supply the ports to publish as a keyword argument. Note that in this implementation, the expectation is argument is a dictionary:

```
t1 = DockerOperatorWithExposedPorts(image=..., task_id=..., port_bindings={5000: 5000, 8080:8080, ...})
```