# Docker Port Failure EADDRINUSE

Tags: docker

I am totally new on Docker and I want to set up a hello world project with Docker.

Currently, I'm using Apache on port 80 as a web server and I don't want to kill PID.

Here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY src/ /usr/src/myapp
EXPOSE 80
```

after I run `docker build -t hello-world .`, simply run `docker run -p 80:80 hello-world` and found that the port in USED, so I changed the port to : `docker run -p 8080:80 hello-world` and I got `Interactive shell`.

so after research on google, I was able to run the server with this command :

```
docker container run --publish 8080:80 nginx
```

Here is the question: How can I run the hello world app with 8080 port on my local computer?

Comment: What docker version do you have? On which host? That Docker host is a VM? What OS your local computer is  using?

Comment: Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4 , OS is  Mac OS X

Comment: So does http://127.0.0.1:8080 works? What are you trying to run? Apache hello-world or NGiNX?

Comment: Yes, it works on browser and i see the welcome message of nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I run the hello world app with 8080 port on my local computer?

That is what `-p 8080:80` (as seen in [container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)) does: Map TCP port 80 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host.

That means on your local computer, http://127.0.0.1:8080 should display the NGiNX welcome message.

But depending on your docker setup, you might have some additional mapping to do (between the VM which hosts Docker, and Docker itself), as I explain in "[Docker ports are not exposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414537/6309)".

---

> I just want echo hello world in PHP, I tried [docker container run --publish 8080:80 hello-world] but i got this : Interactive shell

That is expected: your image is based on the [php one](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), more precisely the [7.2-cli](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c88c3d52f41a370f3a62e3ded62b7b223b4cb846/7.2/stretch/cli/Dockerfile), whose [main command is](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c88c3d52f41a370f3a62e3ded62b7b223b4cb846/7.2/stretch/cli/Dockerfile#L215-L217) (using [`7.2/stretch/cli/docker-php-entrypoint`](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/c88c3d52f41a370f3a62e3ded62b7b223b4cb846/7.2/stretch/cli/docker-php-entrypoint) script):

```
docker-php-entrypoint php -a
```

You should use an [image variant](http://7.2/stretch/cli/docker-php-entrypoint) like a `php:<version>-apache` in order to see an application running, like in [`mfieldhouse/docker-php-helloworld`](https://github.com/mfieldhouse/docker-php-helloworld)
With docker-php-entrypoint

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY src/ /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
```

With src including an `index.php` file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World from Docker! <br>";
echo "Hello ECS! <br>";
echo '<img src="https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/horizontal.png">';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes currently I'm seeing the welcome message of nginx, but I don't know how to see my hello world message from  http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: @Chino You mention the `php` image from which you are building your image in your question. That is not the same as `nginx`. Did you try a `docker container run` of your image with your `-p` option?

Comment: Yes, I just want echo hello world in PHP, I tried [docker container run --publish 8080:80 hello-world] but i got this : Interactive shell

Comment: @Chino OK. I have edited my answer to show an actual php-based Docker-running hello-world application.

Comment: Ok, so I should build one more time and after that what should I run? should I run docker container run --publish 8080:80 hello-world?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your time, now it works with this : docker container run --publish 8080:80 hello-world