# Not able to access the docker containerised java web app on exposed port

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, servlets

I have Java web app in docker container.

Now container is exposed on host's port 8080 from container's port 8080 by running docker run command.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 --name myTomcat -v $(pwd)/out/artifacts/DockerJavaWebAppWarExploded:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ tomcat:latest
```

[image]

There is no other process running on 8080 port ,but i am not able to access the application from browser http://localhost:8080/.

Container logs :

[image]

Please help.

It would be appreciated.

Comment: check the logs `docker container logs myTomcat` or launch without `-d` option to see them.

Comment: @michalk , container logs are good(attached in the post itself).

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414479/docker-ports-are-not-exposed?rq=1) question? I am not familiar with tomcat, but you should ensure that the bind address is not localhost.

Comment: @SiyaramMalav you attached a PNG file of some sort to the question.  You need to include the text output from `docker logs`, not an image and definitely not a screenshot of a terminal window.

Comment: Are you sur you can access to your app at 8080 ? (in the container) Try enter in it with `docker exec` and curl at port 8080

Comment: Do you get a 404 error or a connection refused? A 404 error would mean that docker and tomcat are started correctly, but your app is not deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if http://0.0.0.0:8080 returns values. If yes, you may add an enrty for 0.0.0.0 in your hosts file.