# Issue Running Docker Image

Tags: docker

I have a test web application that I can run locally on localhost:8080. I build my application with maven:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

I run the application with the following maven command:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:run
```

Then I can hit localhost url: http://localhost:8080/pokemon/healthcheck
This is a simple test app that I want to dockarize just for a learning experience. I was able to run the python "Hello World" example, so i think i have everything installed in right places. My Dockerfile has the following:

```
FROM tomcat:alpine
RUN ["/bin/rm", "-fr", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"]
RUN ["/bin/mkdir", "/var/log/tomcat8/"]
COPY target/pokemon.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/pokemon.war
```

Then I stop my locally running localhost, I assume I need to do that, and then I build the image with the following command:

```
docker build -t pokesheets .
```

Then I try running it with this command:

```
docker run -it pokesheets:latest
```

The log looks good to me, I see the message in the log that the service has started. The container is running, I can see it. But I cannot get to http://localhost:8080/pokemon/healthcheck. So I tried running the docker image with the following as well:

```
    docker run -it -p 8080:8080 pokesheets:latest
    docker run -d --name pokesheets -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 pokesheets:latest
    docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 pokesheets:latest
    docker container run -d --name pokesheets -p 8080:8080 pokesheets:latest
```

I have a suspicion that maybe there is something very basic that I'm not aware of. I would very much appreciate input from someone who has some experience with the docker and could shed light on the issue.

Comment: Have you expose the port in your Dockerfile? Look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414479/docker-ports-are-not-exposed

Comment: @NIravModi `EXPOSE` instruction is just for documentation purposes, doesn't have any functionality. From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) : The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.

Comment: I agree with you @leopal

Comment: I did take a look at the EXPOSE earlier, but it didn't look like this is something I'd need @NIravModi.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually running the server inside the Docker container.

You build it and copy files into it, but you are not starting the server.

Use the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) instruction.

**Edit:**

Tomcat official Docker image repo specifies to use the CMD instruction and also utilizes the `:8888` port.

```
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

**Edit 2:**

Build image: `docker build -t pokesheets .`

```
FROM tomcat:alpine

RUN ["/bin/rm", "-fr", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"]
RUN ["/bin/mkdir", "/var/log/tomcat8/"]
ADD target/pokemon.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/pokemon.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Run container

```
docker run -it -p 80:8080 pokesheets:latest
```

Visit `http://localhost:8080/pokemon/healthcheck`

Comment: Would I need both, the ENTRYPOINT and the above CMD?

Comment: No, you would most likely only use one. Stick to the official recommendation from Tomcat image repository, which is the `CMD`. Unless you had a specific reason to use the other.

Comment: I added CMD into the Dockerfile, remover old image, made a new one and tried running it with 'docker run -it -p 8080:8080 pokesheets:latest', but still getting page 'This site can’t be reached'.

Comment: [Image official documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) binds the `:8888` port to the `:8080` host port. Did try like that? `-p 8888:8080` and visit `8080` on your browser.

Comment: I just tried running it again with 8888:8080, then tried my link 8080, then with 8888, still no luck. The log does show the server is running: 'INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 17559 ms'

Comment: @lw0 Added an updated Dockerfile and additional commands to 'Edit 2'. Try that.

Comment: Wow! that made the difference, although not for 8080 port - With the EDIT 2 I can reach the page with http://localhost/pokemon/healthcheck , but not with 8080. But you know, that's a win nonetheless!  Thank you!