# getting error when using ssh to connect to a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

I got a container that has openssh installed and can be connnected via the command
`ssh 172.17.0.2`.

Now I want to get a port (say 32769) on the host side, and map the port 22 (of docker container) to it, the reason for doing that is I want to get the `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 32769` works on localhost, I got the errors as : `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` . The port mapping is showing normally on docker engine:  `0.0.0.0:32769->22/tcp`.

Can somebody help me with that? Much appreciated!

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What's the image the container is running?

Comment: I was starting the container in the python style. The mounting appears has no error, but what was wrong is the -container-ip in the process of docker-proxy: /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32812 -container-ip 172.21.1.2 -container-port 22, the container ip can work with 172.17.0.2 which is eth0. I wonder if I can manually correct the container ip.

Comment: Tried to ping 172.21.1.2, it was unreachable: From 172.21.1.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable. 172.17.0.2 was doing fine: PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=16.1 ms

Comment: The container IP address is an internal implementation detail, and you should completely ignore it.  (Among other things, it can change whenever you delete and restart a container.)

Comment: I think it has been set to my eth1, so no matter how many times I restart the container, it will always be the ip of my eth1.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the SSH daemon is running in your container first (through a [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) or [`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) session):

```
service ssh status
# or
service sshd status
```

Make sure you have the right IP address

```
sudo docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" Container_Name
```

Use the right SSH URL:

```
ssh root@172.17.0.2
```

See more in "[How to SSH into a Running Docker Container and Run Commands](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-ssh-into-docker-container)" from Sofija Simic.

Using a [`docker run -p 32769:22`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35414537/6309) is in your case a good idea.

---

The OP mentions in the discussion an issue with docker proxy:

> The docker-proxy was not getting eth0 of the container as `-container-ip`.
> Here is what I've got
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 32785 \
>                       -container-ip 172.21.1.2 -container-port 22
> ```

Comment: Yep, the sshd service is up in docker container. Actually I can connect to the container via the ssh 172.17.0.2. My question is how can I connect to it by the style ssh 127.0.0.1 -p [mapping port].

Comment: @MingoPan CAn you show the result of a `docker ps` for that container, to see what ports are laready exposed?

Comment: 0.0.0.0:32778->22/tcp, the ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 32778 is not working for me. Got the error: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: @MingoPan  127.0.0.1? Why  127.0.0.1? Why not using the container IP address?

Comment: Interesting, I has tried docker inspect, apparently I got nothing on port 22."PortBindings": {
                "22/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": ""
                    }
                ]
            },

Comment: @MingoPan That is because the docker image has no `EXPOSE` directive for that port (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: I am requried to do so, : (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224955/discussion-between-vonc-and-mingo-pan).