# How to reach localhost services from docker container with IPv4?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6, ipv4

I have this `docker-compose` file where I have a couple of services:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    container_name: mobile_app_api
    env_file:
      - .env.development
    command: npm run watch:dev
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
    extra_hosts:
      - host-machine:host-gateway
    network_mode: host

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    container_name: mobile_app_cache

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: mobile_app_database
    restart: "unless-stopped"
    environment:
      TZ: 'GMT'
      PGTZ: 'GMT'
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: mobile_app_database
    volumes:
      - /:/data/postgres
    network_mode: host
```

Api is supposed to work on `localhost:3333`, but when I start this with `docker-compose up --build` in terminal I get this:

```
mobile_app_api | server running on http://[::1]:3333
```

And here is 2 things.

1. Why does it work on `IPv6`?
2. How can I change host and make it work on `localhost`?

**PS.** My computer is MacOS, but in settings I have turned off `IPv6`.

I was trying to use `host.docker.internal` (and `gateway.docker.internal`) in my compose file, but it didn't work:

```
extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

Comment: This is something in your application configuration, not in the Docker setup.  It must listen on IPv4 `0.0.0.0` or IPv6 `::` (either is fine, even if you think you've disabled IPv6) or it will be unreachable from outside Docker; see for example [Containerized Node server inaccessible with server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414479/containerized-node-server-inaccessible-with-server-listenport-127-0-0-1).

Comment: On a MacOS host `network_mode: host` does not work and you also need to remove that setting.  You also do not need to specify `extra_hosts:` or `container_name:`.  You should not need to override the image's command or the code built into the image, and I'd also recommend removing the main container's `command:` and `volumes:`.