# Not able to connect to an app running on a docker container via browser in mac

Tags: macos, docker

I was trying to running a docker image from a gitlap repository as mentioned in https://codebabel.com/ci-gitlabci-docker/

I ran  the image as shown below and it started

```
docker run  -p 5000:50000 -it registry.gitlab.com/bacdef/flaskapp:latest
 * Serving Flask app "helloworld" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 259-006-586
```

But when I try to access it via browser http://127.0.0.1:5000/ or http://localhost:5000/ or http://myip:5000/ it reply as follows

```
This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

docker ps command output ias as follows

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
04cc5dc26ec5        registry.gitlab.com/bacdef/flaskapp:latest   "python helloworld.py"   18 minutes ago      Up 18 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->50000/tcp   hardcore_perlman
```

I am running it on a **mac os.**

Tried solution of similar questions like [How to access webserver running in docker container from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582899/how-to-access-webserver-running-in-docker-container-from-browser), https://superuser.com/questions/1204030/cannot-access-to-http-localhost4000-after-i-map-this-port-number-to-docker but it does not work.

Can somebody please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your app runs on port 5000 but you're forwarding to port 50000 in the container. Change 50000 to 5000 and it should work.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake. @Paulpro Thanks. Now it works fine